# Spring 3 -- 404 error using a ModelAndView

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, modelandview

I am getting this 404 error message

```
The requested resource (/ghs1986/WEB-INF/pages/poll1.jsp) is not available.
```

from this controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/poll1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processPoll1(@RequestParam String vote) {
    poll1DAO.tallyVote(vote);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("PollPage");
    modelAndView.addObject("PollPage", new Cookie("poll1", "voted"));
    return modelAndView;    
}
```

Here is ghs1986-servlet.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources location="WEB-INF/pages/images/" mapping="/images/**" />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ghs86" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="commentValidator" class="com.validator.CommentValidator" />

    <bean id="commentDAO" class="com.dao.CommentDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="poll1DAO" class="com.dao.Poll1DAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="poll2DAO" class="com.dao.Poll2DAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="poll3DAO" class="com.dao.Poll3DAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="commentController" class="com.controller.CommentController">
        <property name="commentDAO" ref="commentDAO" />
        <property name="commentValidator" ref="commentValidator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pollController" class="com.controller.PollController">
        <property name="poll1DAO" ref="poll1DAO" />
        <property name="poll2DAO" ref="poll2DAO" />
        <property name="poll3DAO" ref="poll3DAO" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="poll1Tag" class="com.tags.Poll1Tag" />

    <bean id="poll2Tag" class="com.tags.Poll2Tag" />

    <bean id="poll3Tag" class="com.tags.Poll3Tag" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you paste your application-servlet.xml

Comment: I just edited my post to add ghs1986-servlet.xml.

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access? What is the requestmapping on your controller class?

Comment: In my browser, I have http://localhost:8080/ghs1986/poll1.  There is no request mapping on the controller class as a whole.  The request mapping on the controller method is shown in my original post.

Comment: Have you tried this URL -- `/ghs1986/poll1.jsp` Note: Controller should not have any mapping and for future remember you cannot access anything under WEB-INF directly (Thats by design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I changed the method to return a String and returned the following:

```
return "redirect:/polls";
```